# store reference variable in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, return, return-type

I have been struggling hard to find the difference between the following two pieces of code.

This ...

```
int z=10;
int y=&z;
```

... is invalid whereas the following does not throw any error:

```
int& foo()
{
    int z=10;
    return z;
}
main()
{
    int y=foo();
    cout<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run the program it returned `y=10`.

My question is:

If `y` can store the reference of another variable using `foo()`, why not directly using `y=&z`?

Comment: The first wrong because `&z` is a pointer to `int`. The second is undefined behaviour because it returns a reference to a local variable.

Comment: "int y=&z" here you are storing address ...not it's reference...

Answer (score 6):

```
 int y=&z;
```

The ampersand above does not indicate `y` is a reference, instead you're applying the address of operator to `z`, meaning you're taking its address.

```
 int& y=z;
```

Here `y` is a reference to `z`.

---

In your second example you have undefined behavior because the function `foo()` returns a reference to a variable that is local to the function. The storage for `z` within `foo()` will cease to exist when the function returns, and then accessing it via the returned reference is undefined behavior.

Comment: The meaning of `&` is completely different in these two cases; it'd be nice if a different symbol had been used for declaring a reference (but all common symbols are in use already so perhaps that wasn't an option!)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create reference variable do

```
int z=10;
int& y=z;
//int y = &z; this is not correct.
```

Answer (score 1):

`y` store values, not references, because `y` is defined `int y` instead of `int& y`. Because of this `foo( )` returns a reference, but `y` stores the value of the reference... that is `10`.

Next code will fail:

```
int& foo()
{
    int z=10;
    return z;
}
main()
{
    int& y = foo(); // <-- now y is a reference
    cout<<y;        // <-- at this point z does not exists
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `y` doesn't store the value of anything. It is UB at the point where `foo()` gets called and the return used to initialize `y`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this code:

```
int& foo()
{
    int z=10;
    return z;
}
```

z is an internal variable whose scope is with-in foo function. As soon as function body ends, z is no more in the memory. But we have passed the reference of internal variable to the outer world (which is out of its scope).

Answer (score 0):

```
int z=10; // create integer z and set it to the value 10.
int y=&z; // create integer y and set it to the address of z
```

The code above doesn't have anything to do with references....

```
int &y = z; // create a reference (y) to integer z
```

Is more like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, a reference variable is similar to an alias (as-if having different name for accessing the same variable). As such,

```
int z=10;
int &y=z; // y is a reference variable, and shares same space of z
y++; // this makes z++ effectively, i.e. z becomes 11
```

and

```
int y = &z; // your example is wrong, as rvalue is int * and lvalue is int
```

Now, when you have,

```
int& foo()
{
    int z=10;
    return z;
}
main()
{
    int y=foo();
    cout<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

This is dangerous, as you are returning reference of a local variable (z) which is going to be destroyed upon returning from foo.
This should have been used like returning a value (instead of reference), as local variables go out of scope upon return from function. Thus, correct usage is:

```
int foo() // return by value
{
    int z=10;
    return z;
}
main()
{
    int y=foo();
    cout<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.
Advise is that never ever return reference of a local variable.

Answer (score -2):

When you use the function, you're simply indicating that the function doesn't push the value on the stack, it instead returns the value by reference.  Somewhat pointless for a simple int, but more useful if you're returning a struct or class.

In the `y=&z` case, you're attempting to set an int equal to an address.

Comment: This is not my comment, but strangely my points got deducted, sum bug in stackoverflow pointing system?